# Keycloak AuthenticationFlowContext return always http protocol

Tags: keycloak

I'm implementing Authenticator class and use AuthenticationFlowContext. When I refer to the server via HTTPS, in context.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath() still leaves http://{hostname}/auth/... .

```
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {

    String url = context.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath()+"?client_id="+context.getClientSession().getClient().getClientId()
            +"&redirect_uri="+context.getClientSession().getNote("redirect_uri")
            +"&state="+context.getClientSession().getNote("state")
            +"&response_type="+context.getClientSession().getNote("response_type");

    try {
        url = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    context.forceChallenge(Response.seeOther(URI.create(idpUrl+"idp/l?lvl=2&url="+url)).build());

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must configure keycloak [server](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html/server-installation.html#d4e390) and nginx:

```
location /  {
       proxy_set_header Host                $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port    443;

       proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
    }
```

Https is enabled.